# C++\Win32 Confused about WaitForSingleObject function return value meaning

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I have a mutex created with `CreateMutex`, and then I use `WaitForSingleObject` to wait on some thread until such time that the Mutex is released and take ownership of it (with no timeout).

So, if the function returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, I can go on my marry way and execute the threads' code.

However, in case the function returns `WAIT_ABANDONED`, can I still execute the code, expecting that any other thread calling `WaitForSingleObject` on my Mutex is going to get stuck until I release?

---

In case the owning thread terminates without releasing the Mutex, I want the calling thread to take ownership and things to keep going as usual.

---

EDIT: what is confusing to me is that MSDN says the state of the mutex in case (2) is unsignaled as opposing to state (1) where it is signaled. What does that mean for me?

Comment: Useful info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/12/463977.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `WAIT_ABANDONED` back, that means you have taken ownership of the mutex. The problem is that you don't know the state of the resource that is being protected by it.

For example, let's say Thread X gets a mutex and starts manipulating the state of something protected by that mutex, and then gets killed. The state is unknown and the mutex is unheld. When you go to wait on that mutex, you will receive it, but you won't know that state.

Comment: In my particular case, I don't care for the state of the resource due to the nature of the work that the threads are up to. But I read that it also means that the state of the Mutex is 'unsignaled' vs the 'signaled' state that its in when returning with the former value.

Answer (score 1):

Getting WAIT_ABANDONED indicates a pretty gross problem in your code.  You'll get this status code when a thread owns a mutex but it terminated without calling ReleaseMutex().

It could be a simple mistake in your code, just forgetting to call that function.  It could be a sign of something *really* nasty, the thread died on an exception and swallowed it.  But didn't properly clean-up state, including forgetting to release the mutex.  Swallowing exceptions without clean-up is always a nasty bug generator that makes programs fail unpredictably and undiagnosably.

Comment: You have a point, I intent to add some code to gracefully terminate the threads so that this does not happen. However in the unlikely case this happens, I still don't care about the state of the resource, as my threads can handle all of its possible states anyway.